# Guava multiple interface and generics, got error "The method XXX in the type XXX is not applicable for the arguments"

Tags: java, generics, guava, predicate

Predicate **and()** method is defined like this :

```
 com.google.common.base.Predicates.and(Predicate<? super T>, Predicate<? super T>)
```

I have three interfaces with the third extending others :

```
public interface IFolderable {
    String getFolder();
}

public interface IId {
    int getId();
}

public interface IBoth extends IFolderable, IId {}
```

And an object implementing the third:

```
public class MyClass implements IBoth {
     String getFolder() {
          return "myFolder";
     }
     int getId() {
          return 1;
     }
}
```

I want to do something like this :

```
    List<MyClass> list = Lists.newArrayList();
    Collections2.filter(list, Predicates.and(new Predicate<IFolderable>() {
         // core predicate using getFolder();
    }, new Predicate<IId>() {
         // core predicate using getId();
    }));
```

But this code generate this error at compile time :

> The method `and(Predicate<? super T>, Predicate<? super T>)` in the type
>   Predicates is not applicable for the arguments (`new Predicate<IFolderable>(){}`, `new Predicate<IId>(){}`)

How can I mix two predicates specialized on one interface over the and() guava method, in order to filter a list of MyClass ?

More generally, how can I specialized generic method in that way ?

*I don't want to declare Predicate with IBoth generic type, because I have other object implementing just IFolderable or IId. (I don't want to have a `new Predicate<IBoth>`)*

Comment: Shouldn't your and(ed) Predicates be of the same type though?
e.g. it'll probably work if your Predicates' type is `IBoth`

Comment: This seems like you'd needing dynamic types - as OP mentioned the list should be able to contain objects that are just IFolderable and objects that are just IId and somehow have an AND of 2 predicates, one for each type, but this is not possible in Java. I think in this case both IFolderable and IId should extend something else, and then your predicate should be of "that something else type" and then in the predicates you try down-casting to each expected type and return true if cast fails otherwise you can use getFolder or getId as is the case.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, your code works fine for me after fixing the errors.